# Aptana and Eclipse SVN Connector not Listed

Tags: eclipse, svn, aptana

I've reinstalled a number of different times... tried both SVNKit (many versions) and JavaHL. Nothing connects to the SVN repos. See attached screen shots. I've tried all the options for connectors. They always seems grayed out in the options. Any help would be appreciated.
[image: Error:]

[image: Greyed out??]

[image: Options, tried all of them.]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact problem, there weren't any Subversive SVN connectors to choose from in the drop down control.

Software configuration:
OS: Windows 7 Professional 64-bit
Java: JDK Version 8 Update 40 32-bit
Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.6.1.201410201044

Here are the steps I did to troubleshoot and fix the problem.

1. See if the log file had any useful information.  In Aptana Studio access the menu Help/Aptana/View Log File.  The error I had was very similar to what Geek Grid had.
2. Installed TortoiseSVN to verify that I could connect to the local network repository.
3. Uninstalled everything related to SVN in Aptana, restarted the app as prompted.
4. Added a software site, http://download.eclipse.org/technology/subversive/2.0/update-site/ and selected the 'Subversive SVN Team Provider' to install.
    Originating URL: http://www.polarion.com/products/svn/subversive/download.php, Section 'Latest Stable Build'
5. In Aptana, navigated to menu item Window/Preferences then Team/SVN and selected the second tab, SVN Connector.  During the first run, there was a helpful button to get connectors.
   I picked SVNKit 1.8.7
6. In Aptana, File/Import.../SVN/Project from SVN, Configured the SVN connection to http://{host}/svn/{Repository name} and entered the security credentials, Project Structure settings left at standard, and finished out of the wizard dialogs.

DONE!

Condensed version.  Couldn't get the provided SVN install to work, went to the main developer's website and got the latest stable build.